# Telerik RadGrid Does not Show

Tags: telerik, radgrid

I have a RadGrid That is used in several ASPX applications.  It works fine in other apps.  However when I copy and paste it into this aspx page it does not work.  I get no error messages and the OnNeedData method shows records being pulled.  All I get is a white line where the RadGrid should appear.  Below is the RAdGrid Setup

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGridSubject" runat="server"
                                    OnInsertCommand="RadGridSubject_InsertCommand"
                                    OnUpdateCommand="RadGridSubject_UpdateCommand"
                                    AllowAutomaticInserts="false"
                                    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                    OnNeedDataSource="RadGridSubject_NeedDataSource"
                                    AllowAutomaticDeletes="false"
                                    MasterTableView-AllowAutomaticInserts="true">
                                    <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="false" CommandItemDisplay="Top"
                                        DataKeyNames="CaseId_FK, SubjectId" Font-Size="Medium"
                                        NoMasterRecordsText="No Subjects Entered"
                                         CommandItemSettings-AddNewRecordText="Add New Subject">
                                        <Columns>
                                            <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" UniqueName="EditCommandColumn" />
                                            <telerik:GridDateTimeColumn DataField="ReceivedDate" HeaderText="ReceivedDate" SortExpression="OrderDate"
                                                PickerType="DatePicker" EnableTimeIndependentFiltering="true" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}">
                                            </telerik:GridDateTimeColumn>
                                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="SubjectName" HeaderText="Subject Name" DataField="SubjectName"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                            <telerik:GridDateTimeColumn DataField="SubjectDOB" HeaderText="DOB" SortExpression="DOB"
                                                PickerType="DatePicker" EnableTimeIndependentFiltering="true" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}">
                                            </telerik:GridDateTimeColumn>
                                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Race" HeaderText="Race" DataField="SubjectRace"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Sex" HeaderText="Sex" DataField="SubjectSex"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="JackectNumnber" HeaderText="Jackect #" DataField="Jacketnum"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="SID" HeaderText="SID #" DataField="SID"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="FBI" HeaderText="FBI #" DataField="FBI"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="SubjectOther" HeaderText="Other" DataField="SabjectOtherInfo"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn AllowFiltering="false">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnSubjectDelete" CssClass="btn btn-xs btn-danger" Text="Delete" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubjectDelete_Click" OnClientClick="confirmAspButton(this); return false;"></asp:Button>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                        </Columns>
                                        <EditFormSettings UserControlName="SubjectEdit.ascx" EditFormType="WebUserControl" PopUpSettings-Modal="false">
                                            <EditColumn UniqueName="EditCommandColumn1"></EditColumn>
                                        </EditFormSettings>
                                    </MasterTableView>
                                </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Why would it work on other pages within the web app but not this one?  When you copy and paste a RADGrid do I need to reset all of the properties?

Comment: In the code behind have you set up your event listeners for RadGridSubject_InsertCommand etc...?

Answer (score 0):

This was an error on my part.  I failed to Bind the RadGrid once I did that the control worked as designed.